# A specific dua I don't know the content of

Tags: dua

I have a question about the following dua:

(Excuse me because it's not in arabic letters.)

What is the following dua about?

Rabi awzini an ashkura nihmataka alati anhamta haleiha wahala walidaiha wa an ahmala salihan tardahoe wa adgilni birahmatika fi hibadika salihin amien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> رب أوزعني أن أشكر نعمتك التي أنعمت علي وعلى والدي وأن أعمل صالحا ترضاه وأدخلني برحمتك في عبادك الصالحين
>
> "My Lord, enable me to be grateful for Your favor which You have bestowed upon me and upon my parents and to do righteousness of which You approve. And admit me by Your mercy into [the ranks of] Your righteous servants."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 27:19](http://quran.com/27/19)</sup>